# Connecting a java soap client to a SSL enabled connection

Tags: java, soap, ssl

I'm working on creating a soap server using java for my company. We have a website that uses SSL set up already, and I'm interested in using SSL for the soap server from the start. I've searched for articles or information about how to implement this, but most of them that I found are things such as "you need a cert first" or are so old and missing parts that I cannot contact the creator.

How would I go about connecting the soap server using SSL? Is there anything special I need to do in the code to enable SSL? The cert is already applied and we have working HTTPS connections already running through our website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most (probably all) SOAP frameworks will support ssl.  Here is a [link](http://lehvolk.blogspot.ca/2012/03/java-soap-implementations-with-ssl.html) with some example code for Axis2, Apache CXF and JAX-WS.